# how to work on stl stacks inside functions c++?

Tags: c++, stl, stack

I am new to stl in c++. I would like to know how can we work on an stl stack inside a function such that the globally declared stack which i pass to the function is modified as we modify  the local stack inside the function .Is there a way to achieve this?

example- i want to do modification inside stack 'a' inside fill , will s1 be affected this way?..if not what to do?

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<stack>

    using namespace std;

    stack<int> s1;
    stack<int> s2;

    void fill(stack<int> a,int cap){
                 .........
    }

  int main()
  {
       int n;
       fill(s1,n);
       return 0;
  }
```

Comment: are you talking about `std::stack`, or how memory is handled, or neither? I have no idea what you're asking

Comment: There is no such thing as "the globally declared stack". If this is something you create or it's provided to you, you will need to explain that clearly.

Comment: i could understand the process if i created the stack myself but stl is causing confusion

Comment: Using a global variable or a local variable has nothing to do with the standard library specifically.

Comment: @UdayanBaidya Still no idea what the "confusion" is. Consider providing a small sample code that is "causing confusion" and explain why you are confused. Otherwise, I doubt you will get any answer.

Comment: i have provided an example hope it helps

Comment: s1 will not be affected because you are passing a copy of it to the fill function. Use pass-by-reference instead: fill(stack<int>& a) {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `fill` function takes the parameter `a` by value, which means a copy is made. No changes to `a` inside the function will affect the variable you passed to the function.

I suggest you make the function pass the object by reference:

```
void fill(stack<int>& a, int cap)
```

Now changes to `a` will update the object your passed. The fact that you may be passing a global variable to the function doesn't matter here.

Comment: Thnak you very much :-)